# What function do I use in a Salesforce apex trigger to trim a text field?

Tags: triggers, apex, salesforce-service-cloud

I'm new to writing apex triggers. I've looked through a lot of the apex developer documentation, and I can't seem to find the combination of functions that I *should* use to automatically trim characters from a text field.

My org has two text fields on the Case object, which automatically store the email addresses that are included in an email-to-case. The text fields have a 255 character limit each. We are seeing errors pop up because the number of email addresses that these fields contain often exceeds 255 characters.

I need to write a trigger that can trim these text fields to the last ".com" *before* it hits the 255 character limit.

Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace()` function in Apex.

```
String s1 = 'abcdbca';
String target = 'bc';
String replacement = 'xy';
String s2 = s1.replace(target, replacement);
```

If you need to use regular expression to find the pattern, then you can use `replaceAll()`

```
String s1 = 'a b c 5 xyz';
String regExp = '[a-zA-Z]';
String replacement = '1';
String s2 = s1.replaceAll(regExp, replacement);
```

For more information please refer [Apex Reference Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_replace)

Answer (score 0):

The following code I think that covers what you are searching:

```
String initialUrl = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69136581/what-function-do-i-use-in-a-salesforce-apex-trigger-to-trim-a-text-field';
Integer comPosition = initialUrl.indexOf('.com');

System.debug(initialUrl.left(comPosition + 4));
//https://stackoverflow.com
```

The main problems that I see are that other extensions are not covered (like ".net" urls) and that urls that have a ".com" appearing previous to the last one (something like "https://www.comunications.com"). But I think that this covers most of the use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Why not increasing the length of that specific field? Trimming the text might cause data loss or unusable. Just go to object manager find that object and that specific field. Edit field and increase the length.